# C++ If inside While

Tags: c++, xml

I want to parse some data from an XML Document, im using a while loop.

```
Poco::XML::NodeIterator it(_pDocument, Poco::XML::NodeFilter::SHOW_ELEMENT);
Poco::XML::Node* pNode = it.nextNode();

pNode = it.nextNode();

while (pNode)
{ 
    std::cout<<pNode->nodeName()<<" :"<< pNode->nodeValue() << "\n";

    if (pNode->nodeName() == "name")
    {
        std::cout << "Loading Map with Name : " << getString(pNode->nodeName()) << "\n";
    }

    if (pNode->nodeName() == "actor")
    {
        std::cout << "Actor Type : " << getString("actor[@type]") << "Actor Name : " <<   getString("actor[@name]") << "\n";
    }
    pNode = it.nextNode();
}
```

This works (albeit probably not the best solution). However, in my XML there are 2 actor elements with different values but the code returns the values of the first element twice.

edit:

```
<thorium>
<name>SampleLevel</name>

<actor type="1Volume" name="m_pActor1" enabled="true">
<attribute name="Rotation" value="-1.0 1.0 0.0"/>
<attribute name="Position" value="-1.2 0.0 0.0"/>
</actor>

<actor type="2Volume" name="m_pActor2" enabled="false">
<attribute name="Rotation" value="1.0 1.0 0.0"/>
<attribute name="Position" value="1.2 0.0 0.0"/>
</actor>
```

Comment: Please show an exemplary XML markup.

Comment: there are a lot of question marks here. what is `pNode`? what is `nodeName`? What does `getString` do? how do you read the XMLfile? What does your XMLfile look like?

Comment: Also: 0) Please _use_ the preview function and make your question readable. 1) Don't mix tabs and spaces, especially on the web 2) Don't use `std::endl` if you do not want to explicitly flush buffers. Use just \n instead 3) provide a minimal testcase

Comment: Also: Are you sure that "C++ If inside While" is the problem you want to solve?

Comment: Similar to phresnel's suggestions: Make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getString` isn't using `it` or `pNode`, so it has no way to know whether you're looking at the first or the second occurrence.  It looks like you're passing `getString` an XPath query.  So it's returning whatever that query matches when executed on the entire document.

You probably want `pNode->attributes`